WinUI 3 Custom Control Property Binding doesnt work
I created a Custom control that is supossed to be used as a button in an item View, however, the binding to change its text doesnt work.
CustomControls(Winui3 class library project)/CustomTableItem.cs
namespace CustomControls
{
    public sealed class CustomTableItem : Control
    {

        DependencyProperty TableNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(TableName),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CustomTableItem),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public string TableName
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TableNameProperty);
            set => SetValue(TableNameProperty, value);
        }

        public CustomTableItem()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomTableItem);
        }

        public CustomTableItem(string TableName)
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomTableItem);
            this.TableName = TableName;
        }
    }
}

CustomControls/Themes/Generic.xaml
//one other style above [...]

<Style TargetType="local:CustomTableItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomTableItem">
                <Grid Height="150" Width="150" Background="White">
                    <TextBlock Text="..." Height="15" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        Text="{Binding TableName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='Error Binding'}"
                        Style="{StaticResource BodyStrongTextBlockStyle}" 
                        FontSize="20"
                        >
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

View(packaged winui3 project)/CustomTablePage.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="View.CustomTablePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:View"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:customControls ="using:CustomControls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">


    <customControls:CustomTableItem TableName="This doesnt show in the label"/>

The CustomTablePage is shown using the ContentFrame.Navigate() function
End result:

When I place the exact same control in a page that is instantiated once and reused(ContentFrame.Content = PageObject) The Property works:

Other page location: View/PageName.xaml.
Code:
<CustomControls:CustomTableItem TableName="Custom table name"></CustomControls:CustomTableItem>
I've tried changing the binding in the template text property but it still didnt work. I've seen some answers talking about something called DataContex, but I didnt understand how it works, and I noticed most of them were using user controls instead of custom controls or WPF.
Edit:
After debbuging the bind (following @Andrew KeepCoding answer), and adding an TargetNullValue to the binding line,
Text="{Binding TableName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay, FallbackValue='Error Binding', TargetNullValue='Source is null!'}"

I've narrowed down the problem to the source being null.
Edit 2:
After reviewing in more detail my CustomTablePage constructor code:
namespace View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class CustomTablePage : Page
    {
        public CustomTablePage()
        {

            this.InitializeComponent();
            var item = new CustomTableItem();
            item.TableName = "Test";

            /*itemsViewTables.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<CustomTableItem>
            {
                item

            };*/
        }
    }
}

And commenting the lines:
var item = new CustomTableItem();
item.TableName = "Test";

The button text started showing up, but if I add more than one button, only the last text shows, all the others are null. It looks like there can only be one control of that type by page, no matter if the others are being displayed or not.
Added to CustomTablePage.xaml:
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <customControls:CustomTableItem TableName="hello"/>
        <customControls:CustomTableItem TableName="hello2"/>
        <customControls:CustomTableItem TableName="hello3"/>
        <customControls:CustomTableItem TableName="hello4"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

What is happening now:

Fixed the issue by adding public static readonly to the dependency property declaration:
public static readonly DependencyProperty TableNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
     nameof(TableName),
     typeof(string),
     typeof(CustomTableItem),
     new PropertyMetadata(null));


You should use the Live Visual Tree to debug this type of issues. You can see the properties for each control

I guess you can't see it because the Foreground is White. Right-click the TextBlock and select Show Properties.

Try using TemplateBinding:
<TextBlock Text={TemplateBinding TableName} .../>

I also found that public static readonly doc is missing on your dependency property:
public static readonly DependencyProperty TableNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(TableName),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(CustomTableItem),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));


Thanks for the tip, I saw that the binding failed, and after adding TargetNullValue='Source is null!' to the binding, it appeared in the text that the source is null. I still dont know how it can be null, if it's being clearly assigned in the xaml. Do you have any more tips on how I can debug it?

Your code should work but can you try TemplateBinding instead of Binding? Also, which binding is failing? You are setting the TableName directly to "This doesnt show in the label", right?

Still can't repro the null issue but public static readonly is missing. Check my answer. Can you check that the related code you are posting here is exactly the same with that on your project?

Thanks a lot for the help! Kinda crazy that a simple declaration like that can fix all the binding problems. The weirdest thing is that in the Microsoft tutorial, they dont say any of that. Their code doesnt seem to work, lol!

There tutorial code at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/xaml-templated-controls-csharp-winui-3
for creating the dependcy property is:
DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( nameof(Label), typeof(string), typeof(BgLabelControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLabelChanged)));

Should I try to report that to them?

Check what the doc says about this. I can create an edit request unless you want to create one.
